# How to prevent javascript if statement to evaluate 0 as an empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, operators

I have js object that has data which contains numbers. Some of them can be `0`. In that case if statement will evaluate those values as an empty strings. Here is example:

```js
var dataObj = {
  "one": 13,
  "two": 0,
  "three": 3
}

$.each(dataObj, function (j, k) {
  if(k){
    console.log('Column: '+k);
  }else{
    console.log('Empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering how this can be prevented? Is there a way to check if value is empty but at the same time not consider `0` as an empty value?

Comment: How about `if (k || k === 0)`?

Comment: That works but is that a good practice?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It's guaranteed to behave in a specific way by the language spec.

Comment: Ah, you've stumbled across the loose equality conundrum. Check out this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2535504). You'll want to use `===` over `==` and depending on what possible valid values (say `null` or `""`) check against those. So `if ( k !== null && k !== "" ) { console.log('Gotcha!'); }` Edit: [here's a good read on truthy and falsy values in JS](https://javascript.info/ifelse#boolean-conversion).

Comment: So do not do a truthy check? Check for an empty string? `if (k != '')`

Comment: Is not evaluating as empty string. There are numerous falsy values beyond empty string and `0` is one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the condition to `k || k===0` this mean (as far as i know) it will accept `not-undefined`, `not-null`, `not-empty` and `zero int value` as a `true`.

please comment if there anything i can do to improve the answer..

don't forget to checkout my snippet

have a nice day..

```js
var dataObj = {
  "one": 13,
  "two": 0,
  "three": 3,
  "four": null,
  "five": ''
}

$.each(dataObj, function (j, k) {
  // use 'or' operator
  if(k || k===0){
    console.log('Column: '+k);
  }else{
    console.log('Empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `k==0` with Logical operator (`||`) as part of the condition which will pass through the condition when the value is `0`.

Try

```
if(k || k == 0){
```

```js
var dataObj = {
  "one": 13,
  "two": 0,
  "three": 3
}

$.each(dataObj, function (j, k) {
  if(k || k == 0){
    console.log('Column: '+k);
  }else{
    console.log('Empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this a duplicate of a previous answer (and should be a comment anyway, given that this is a question about good practice, not really about solving a problem)

Comment: @ChrisG, why the comment is only under one answer not under another.....voting to close would be more meaningful than commenting.